# How to get rid of Laravel mix blank screen

Tags: laravel, vue.js, composer-php, laravel-mix, inertiajs

I'm getting a blank screen after moving a laravel 8 mix working project from CentOs 8 to my windows 10 local xampp server.

I used to get 500 error but after doing the following steps, I'm now getting a blank screen, when I do view page source it seems the contents of my page are there. But what I noticed is, under view source when I try to click on the link to the app.js, and other images & css files its saying file not found. The project seems to be compiled by laravel-mix.

1. I installed the composer on my laptop.
2. Downloaded php 7.3.
3. Did composer update to match up with my php version
4. I did composer install inside my working project
5. I did php artisian key:generate
6. I did php artisian cache:clear
7. Changed the configuration in the .env file to match up with my database credentials

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message from your server's error log. Also, are you sure this problem is in any way related to vue.js or any of the other tags? If not, please remove them

Comment: It's showing a blank screen and no server error log. When I did inspect element on the console tab, it's displaying a 404 error app.js not found

Comment: Having a 404 error on any JS file sounds ilke your build process is broken. But I would assume that PHP is not involved in this